# How to auto generate the yaml code for api documentation in swagger editor?

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-editor

I want to design my web api using swagger, but the problem is I have to write all the yaml code myself, which in itself is a time consuming and tedious process. Can this process be automated?

I tried searching but did not anything useful.
Is auto-generation of yaml code for api design even possible before creating the api itself.

If yaml code can't be generated automatically then why use swagger for api design.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes a lot, found these types of links and they explain how to write yaml not auto-generate it. https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/pubapis_openapi_step5_components_object.html

Comment: https://swagger.io/tools/open-source/open-source-integrations/ - there are libraries for different programming languages that can generate the OpenAPI definition from source code annotations. For example, Springfox or Swagger Core for Java; Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net for .NET, Swagger-PHP for PHP, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use swashbuckle instead of swagger (or alongside it, but i suggest just picking one)

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#getting-started

They changed the docs since i've used it, however there's this tool you can use that scans your asp.net core project, looks at all controllers and routes and generates an opeapi document for you.

It can also generate client code and a bunch of other things.

Comment: But I have no controller's yet as my api is still in **design** phase. I know by adding swagger dependency into your project and creating a configuration file with docket  method, swagger will auto-generate everything.

Comment: if you're in the design phase, you should design the swagger/OpenApi file. so if you're in the design phase - thats the thing you're designing.

Comment: So that means, there is no way to auto-generate the yaml code at design phase.

Comment: well - how would you want to auto-generate it? theres no generator on earth that can magically gues what you want in that file. Do you perhaps mean you'd like a modeler? a visual app to aid you in designing the specification?

Comment: Exactly what I mean "a visual app to aid you in designing the specification". I think it should available @sommmen

Comment: i don't know of tools like that. I myself used 3 techniques, autogeneration based on controllers in asp.net core, designing the file myself and i also used the swagger site at some point to make a document by sending out rest calls (get/post etc) to an api of another website. I did found this; https://openapi.tools/#gui-editors so there seem to be some helper tools available. https://www.apibldr.com/ this one looks pretty neat!

Answer (score 0):

There are some backend frameworks that will actually do this for you. Can't speak to any language-agnostic solutions, but if you're working in Python, you can use FastAPI. Every API you build with it auto-generates Swagger docs and serves them on a '/docs' route you can navigate to from your backend's base URL. If you want to add extra description information about the routes, there are decorators you can preface the route code with for that purpose.

I've really been enjoying working with it for the past few months. I don't have to write a single line in order to provide basic integration info about my backends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).